# How to know if "disableInitialLoad" was called on GPT?

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I need to know if `googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad()` was called, in which case I'll load an ad using a `display` and a `refresh` calls, otherwise I'll load it using just `display`. My assumption is that if I always call `display` plus `refresh` I will get 2 ad requests unless `disableInitialLoad` had been called.

Is it possible to know that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a method in GPT for doing this which is: [isInitialLoadDisabled()](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_isInitialLoadDisabled)

And as Claudio wrote - it's good practice not to use undocumented variables.
Undocumented variables might not do exactly what you think they do - and their behaviour might change at any point (see [avoiding common GPT implementation mistakes](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/common_implementation_mistakes)).

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented variable on pubads that internally saves the state of disableInitialLoad, because it is undocumented you have to use it under your own risk.

the variable is `window.google_DisableInitialLoad`

Hope it is still usefull to you.